# Oracle SQL database In-Memory - compare compressions sizes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm playing with in-memory storage in oracle sql. I would like to compare the results of compression, I meant the amount of used space. For example, I'm running these queries:

```
ALTER TABLE RENTING INMEMORY MEMCOMPRESS FOR QUERY LOW(RETURN_DATE);
```

vs

```
ALTER TABLE RENTING INMEMORY MEMCOMPRESS FOR CAPACITY HIGH(RETURN_DATE);
```

Is there any easy way to check the size used by these compressions in SQL developer?

I found this article https://blogs.oracle.com/in-memory/database-in-memory-compression, there is a table containing 'space used' for each type of compression. This exactly what I am trying to do on my own. Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying v$im_segments after population will show you how many bytes from the table were loaded and how much of the in-memory store was utilised.

Comment: Yeah, I was using this earlier but it did not show anything for me, because of some other issue. But for this question, this is the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the column space is part of the In-Memory Compression Units (IMCU), there is no way to see how much space is consumed by individual columns. It is possible to display the individual column level compression setting in the view v$im_column_level though. The closest you could come would be to compare the populated size between the two compression levels. As Connor said, you can do this with v$im_segments or you can display individual IMCU information for an object with the view v$im_header.